# PHP version error while run composer in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.6, i am trying to run composer. but its shows php version error.

where as my php version is set correctly. please check the attached screenshot.[image]

please help me to fix this.

Comment: your php version is 5.6

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run composer with PHP5, I assume you got both PHP7 and PHP5 installed and it's defaulting to PHP5.

Since Magento 2 Minimum PHP Version is 7 [See Minimum specs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html)

You can find out what versions of PHP you got installed by running

- **Redhat Distros:** `rpm -qa | grep php`
- **Debian Distros:** `apt list --installed | grep`

Then when you try to run composer you can specify what PHP install you want it to use like so

`php7.1 composer update`

If that still does not work, are you sure you got the CLI interpreter for PHP 7 installed as well
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt-get update && apt-get install php7.1-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Try executing command with ignore platform appended

$ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs